# Ethernet is not working ubuntu 20.04 even after installation of r8168

Tags: 20.04, ethernet

I am connected to internet through wifi. The command `ifconfig` shows `wlo1` but no ethernet. How can I get connected to internet through ethernet? My ethernet socket has a green light on. Ubuntu is 20.04.

I have already installed `r8168`

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

The result of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` is:

```
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
--
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1462:7d16]
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: What is the Ethernet adapter? `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

Comment: I edited and included the output

Comment: I ran this on my computer, and it came up with DLink Gigabit and the Realtek Semiconductor. Perhaps you need two?

Comment: Search here on AU for "RTL8125" and you'll get your answer.

Comment: I found the source of issue. When installing the ubuntu, I selected the "minimal" installation option. I think because of this selection, ubuntu installer did not install the drivers for wifi and ethernet. I reinstalled the ubuntu using full installation option.